# How to investigate domain or http connection issue?

Tags: networking, domain

We are seeing intermittent failures to godaddy.com if hit without subdomain. It also affects our domain hosted there, so trying to gather information to provide support who is not seeing the same issue.

If we hit http://godaddy.com from a number of locations that go through different ISPs we see a connection failure. It will usually be successful after a couple refreshes. My home and office connections see the issue as do services like BrowserStack and https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/godaddy.com, as well as inconsistent results from various uptime monitors.

How can I best inspect this network traffic to gather more information about the issue? Is anyone else seeing the same issue? I am in US mid-atlantic if it is a regional issue.

Expanding on this as requested, we see different output like "The connection was reset, so there is no response" and from python "'Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'".

Comment: Start by describing the actual symptom or error message. Its rather unspecific to talk about *failures*.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me understand what you mean by `Connection failure` from the technical point of view?

When a user tries to access a website and get an error, usually this error would be (1) a DNS error (couldn't resolve domain name) or (2) any kind of access error like "Internal Server Error - HTTP/50x", "Bad request - HTTP/400", "Request timeout - HTTP/408", and the like.

If it's a DNS error, you can try using another DNS Server.
If it's an access error, well, that depends on the error you're getting to better know how to deal with it.

Comment: When hit through python the resulting error is 'Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'.